# Django endless_pagination

Tags: django

Добрый день. Уже продолжительное время пытаюсь подключить к проекту django endless pagination, вот только постоянные натыкаюсь на различные ошибки. 
Код следующий:
students.py (это вьюшка основной страницы, на которой и стараюсь прикрепить пагинацию)

```python
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse

from ..models import Student

from endless_pagination.decorators import page_template


@page_template("students_list_page.html") # just add this decorator
def entry_index(request, template="students_list.html",
    extra_context=None):
    context = {
        'students': Student.objects.all(),
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return render_to_response(template, context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def students_list(request):
    students = Student.objects.all()

    # try to order students list
    order_by = request.GET.get('order_by', '')
    if order_by in ('id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'ticket'):
        students = students.order_by(order_by)
        if request.GET.get('reverse', '') == '1':
            students = students.reverse()
    return render(request, 'students/students_list.html', {'students': students})
```

часть кода из students_list.html:

```html
<tbody>
  {% extends 'students/students_list_page.html' %} {% block js %} {% {{ block.super }} %
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless_on_scroll.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var endless_on_scroll_margin = 5;
  </script>
  {% endblock %} {% include page_template %}
</tbody>
```

students_list_page.html:

```html
{% for student in students %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ forloop.counter}}</td>
  <td>

    {% if student.photo %}
    <img class="img-circle" src="{{ student.photo.url }}" height="30" width="30" />{% else %}
    <img class="img-circle" src="{% static " img/default_user.png " %}" height="30" width="30" />{% endif %}

  </td>
  <td><a href="{% url " students_edit " student.id %}"> {{ student.last_name }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url "students_edit" student.id %}"> {{ student.first_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ student.ticket }}</td>
                    <td>
                      <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                          data-toggle="dropdown"> Дія <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="{% url "students_edit" student.id %}"> Редагувати </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/journal/{{ student.id }}"> Відвідування </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{% url " students_delete " student.id %}"> Видалити </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %} {% show_more %}
```

Ошибку выдает следующую:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но эта часть кода закрывает основной блок, который еще в начале страницы. Если убрать весь код, касающийся подключения пагинация, то страница работает нормально, поэтому полагаю, что ошибка где-то в приведенных мною примерах когда, вот только где, не могу понять.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Вот довольно простой способ сделать пагинацию:

view.py:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def students_list(request):
    students = Student.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(students, 3) # 3 студента на каждой странице
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # Если номер страницы не целое число, то отправляем на первую страницу
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # Возвращаем последую страницу, если вышли за рамки доступных страниц
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'students_list.html', {'page': page,'students': students})
```

Лучше создать отдельный шаблон `pagination.html` для того, чтобы его можно было подключать к любым шаблонам, где требуется пагинация. В `pagination.html` пишем следующее:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
      {% if page.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
      {% endif %}
        <span class="current">Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
      {% if page.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
      {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

В этом шаблоне есть ссылка на предыдущую и следующую страницу, а также номер текущей страницы.

Теперь этот шаблон можно подключить к вашему `students_list.html` следующим образом:

```
{% include "pagination.html" with page=students %}
```

Comment: Такого рода пагинацию я делал. Хотел попробовать прикрутить аля твиттер/фейсбук.

Comment: Т.е. используя ajax?

Comment: Ну в общем-то да.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% block content %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

Зачем вы пытаетесь вставить туда еще раз название блока? Оно передается в открывающий тэг.

Comment: Проблема не в блоке. Даже обойдя ее, все равно наталкиваюсь на другие ошибки. Конечной является:http://piccy.info/view3/9415064/c775af25403557c0b8f8ea4179e4ee61/

Comment: `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` во вторую вьюху попробуйте добавить